# Hybridization theory (orbitals used in different hybridizations)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, hybridization, valence-bond-theory

Why is $d_{x²-y²}$ orbital used in $sp^3d$ (square pyramidal geometry) while $d_{z^2}$ orbital in $sp^3d$ (trigonal bipyramidal geometry)?
I came across this information while reading *J.D.Lee Concise inorganic chemistry*.